# How to view the problematic records in IIDR CDC

Tags: ibm-data-replication

we are using IBM Data Replication CDC. Our target system is IBM Integrated Analytics System (IIAS) and we are using external table mirror bulk apply method to apply changes to IIAS.

When we get errors we want to see the problematic records but couldn't find the file where rejected records are written. Is there a parameter which we can set on CDC to set the path for rejected records or is there a default path for it?

Answer (score 1):

this is Yukun from IBM Data Replication team. The following answer may help you with the problem.

Parameter:

you can enable global_trace_hours parameter which will write the conflicting rows to the target trace "on" directory.

The path for reject records:

Rejected records are written to .bad file that can be configured through external table option "LOGDIR" in /conf/db2loadoptions.xml.

The rejected records file would have format "database.schema.external-table-name.file-name.application-handle.id.bad" and available in the refresh loader path where external table files are written.